# Define user variable in WooCommerce My account custom menu item content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-data

The custom menu is displayed in My Account of woocommerce.
I am making a custom menu with the code below.

```
/**
 * Query registration
 */
function my_custom_query_vars($vars)
{
    $vars[] = 'my-dosu-endpoint';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 0);

function my_custom_my_account_menu_items($items)
{
    $items['my-dosu-endpoint'] = __('OOOO', 'woocommerce');
    return $items;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items');

function my_custom_endpoint_content()
{
}

add_action('woocommerce_account_my-dosu-endpoint_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content');


function my_custom_endpoint_title($title)
{
    global $wp_query;
    $is_endpoint = isset($wp_query->query_vars['my-dosu-endpoint']);
    if ($is_endpoint && !is_admin() && is_main_query() && in_the_loop() && is_account_page()) {
        // New page title.
        $title = __('OOOO', 'woocommerce');
        remove_filter('the_title', 'my_custom_endpoint_title');
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'my_custom_endpoint_title');
```

I would like to display the user information registration form in this custom menu.

I was able to copy and paste the contents of `form-edit-acount.php` and display it using the following:

```
function my_custom_endpoint_content()
{
    defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

    do_action('woocommerce_before_edit_account_form'); ?>

    <form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action('woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag'); ?>>

        <?php do_action('woocommerce_edit_account_form_start'); ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
            <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e('First name', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user->first_name); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
            <label for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e('Last name', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user->last_name); ?>" />
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e('Display name', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user->display_name); ?>" /> <span><em><?php esc_html_e('This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews', 'woocommerce'); ?></em></span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e('Email address', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user->user_email); ?>" />
        </p>

        <fieldset>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e('Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password_1"><?php esc_html_e('New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password_2"><?php esc_html_e('Confirm new password', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php do_action('woocommerce_edit_account_form'); ?>

        <p>
            <?php wp_nonce_field('save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce'); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save changes', 'woocommerce'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Save changes', 'woocommerce'); ?></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
        </p>

        <?php do_action('woocommerce_edit_account_form_end'); ?>
    </form>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_edit_account_form');
}

add_action('woocommerce_account_my-dosu-endpoint_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content');
```

But I have not been able to obtain user information.

Therefore, it corresponds to the non-input check when saving.
"Undefined variable `$user`" is displayed in the `$user` part. Where should I define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First on your last function, `defined('ABSPATH') || exit;` is unnecessary, this is used by php or templates files. Then you need to define `$user` variable, which is an instance of the `WP_User` object (the current user).

So simply replace `defined('ABSPATH') || exit;` with `$user = wp_get_current_user();`.

It should solve that *"Undefined variable `$user`"* issue.

Answer (score 1):

at the beginning of the function :

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
```

if that code doesn't work, this one should make the trick:

```
$user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
```